# How do i access data for SectionList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to create dynamic SectionList  with some data.
i created a example code for my question, here it is my DATA :

```js
const DATAS = [
  (DATA1 = [
    {
      title: "A",
      data: ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    },
    {
      title: "B",
      data: ["F", "O", "F"],
    },
  ]),
  (DATA2 = [
    {
      title: "M",
      data: ["a", "r", "o"],
    },
    {
      title: "T",
      data: ["F", "s", "s"],
    },
  ]),
];

export default DATAS;
```

how can i get access to DATA1 or DATA2,

```js
import  DATAS from .....


const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

function MySectionList(props) {
  
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={//i have no idea }
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

i am really confused. i tried many things but still doesnt work.

Comment: Looks like `sections={DATA[0]}` would work. The [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) show that you must pass an array to `sections`. Since your `DATAS` is exported as an array of arrays of objects, you need to choose which array to pass to the component.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl What about `DATAS[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sections={DATA[0]}` would work. The [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) show that you must pass an array to `sections`. Since your `DATAS` is exported as an array of arrays of objects, you need to choose which array to pass to the component.

---

To show only `DATA1`:

```
function MySectionList(props) {
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={DATAS[0]}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

To show only `DATA1` and `DATA2` as one list:

```
function MySectionList(props) {
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={DATAS.flat()}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

---

**Note:** If you want to render `DATA1` and `DATA2` as separate `SectionList` objects, you will have to render a mapping of each to their own list:

```
function MySectionList(props) {
  const { dataLists } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {
        dataLists.map(dataList => (
          <SectionList
            sections={dataList}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
              <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
            )}
          />
        ))
      }
    </>
  );
}

MySectionList.propTypes = {
  dataLists: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Section)))
};

<MySectionList dataLists={DATAS} />
```